Connecting ionic Android/iOS app over HTTPS with my Local Server
After changes in Ionic App and Local Spring Boot Server, I see this error when switching to HTTPS instead of HTTP, when user tries to login:
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
This is what I have tried so far:

Generated a Self-Signed Certificate, placed in Spring Boot Server and made changes in application.properties

Used the same certificate and placed in ionic android app.

Handled CORS in Spring Boot Server

Updated the network_security_config.xml to allow HTTPS requests.

Created a res/xml/network_security_config.xml file:


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>

In AndroidManifest.xml, reference this file:
    <application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ... >
    </application>


updated the server url in Ionic App - using 10.0.2.2 as server address
Rebuild app in Android Studio and launched in emulator,

